# Need to apply box notation on thick strings from book Improvising Rock guitar green note publ

Tags: guitar, scales

I was reading and practicing with book Improvising Rock Guitar by Green note music publication.

In that book i understood the box notations which are all explained in top 3 or 4 strings the thin strings (D, G,B, E)( page 21 in book)

How to apply the same notations on lower strings (the thick ones), as i can see in rock scale 1(from book, page 23) notes are played in thick strings, whereas in previous chapters there is no where i can find the box notations for thick strings.

If anyone has read that book can you please tell me or for others i have attached some images[[image: image of box notation on thin strings]]
[image: example record where we are using box notation on thick strings]

How is this notation extended from thin to thick strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that method specifically, but without getting more complex: the note "boxes" relate by being down two frets and down two strings.

In Rock Scale 1: III, it starts at 5th fret, sixth (E) string, ends at 7th fret, 4th (D) string. These are the "same note" but an octave apart. If you pick any fret+string combo and go 2up/2up or 2down/2down, you find the same note an octave apart: *but* the B string is tuned differently to make open chord fingerings easier, this breaks the rule slightly.

Note that in Rock Scale 1: VIII, it is the "same box" as III but starting on different strings (2up/2up) and it ends on the B string so it is offset as mentioned above.

Rock Scale 2 is the same set of notes, but starts on A string 12th fret. This is the same as staring on D string 7th fret as in the Scale 1: VIII box

Comment: Got your point absolutely correct. I was also asking that in another image there are boxes of notes in key of A which sound good. Now how those boxes are used in second image where notes are played on thick strings.

Comment: Like which notes will be in box d ext on thick strings.

Comment: Ok got it so same notes are played everywhere on guitar. Thanks